# Writing a program that compares 2 numbers in Python

Tags: python

I am new to python and I do not know how to go about this problem exactly. If I want to compare two integers to see if they are equal, how would I set that up? For example, enter a number for a, enter a  number for b and see if they are equal or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = input("Enter the first number: ")
b = input("Enter the second number: ")
# if a is b: - Compares id's, and can cause inconsistencies. Use == instead.
if a == b:
  print "Both inputs are equal"
else:
  print "Your input is not equal."
```

Comment: does it matter the else part if it is indented or not?

Comment: yes that is how python knows which lines of code are inside the if or not (same for the else)

Comment: after i press enter after print both inputs are equal, do i need to back space for the else?

Comment: Don't use `is` for testing equality. `==` is used for equality comparison.

Comment: what do you mean equality comparison? i got the bases for this questions, but i am just trying to learn as much as i can for now.

Comment: It's true. When you use `is` you're comparing id's. All integers in python are defined in an array of integer object, and you'll actually be comparing these id's, not the values themselves.

Answer (score 3):

```
a=20
b=10
if a==b:
 print "equal"
else:
 print "unequal"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def compare(a, b):
   return a == b
```

You could write a function like this and call it, like so:

```
aNumber = 3
anotherNumber = 4
result = compare(aNumber, anotherNumber)
print(result)
```

Comment: seems rather unnecessary to write a function for that

Comment: He's new to python, I thought it would be worth while to show him the comparison and throw in a function example with it.

Comment: so this would work when you already defined what A or B is?

Comment: added an example of how you would use it.

Comment: I know lots of funtional programmers who might encapsulate `xor`, `is_a,` and other trite activities as a function. *ahem* `print()` *ahem*

Comment: With the python version I'm using print(result) is valid.