# What exactly is wrong with this program?

Tags: python

The following code is supposed to prompt the user for a number, check to see if the number is equal to 30, and print whether it is or not.

The code contains an error and will not run.

Explain what is wrong.

Assume the user actually enters an integer.

```
user_input = input("Enter an integer: ")

user_input = int(user_input)

if user_input = 30:

    print("The user entered 30.")

else:

    print("The user did not enter 30.")
```

I can not pin point what is wrong exactly, when I run it.

I think something is wrong with the `if`, `else` statement part. I have only used Python for 2 weeks now and am still trying to understand it.

Comment: "The code contains an error and will not run." -- It would help greatly if you could say what the error is. Python is likely to say something like "`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`" and point you to a line explaining where the error is.

Comment: Please take a look at http://sscce.org/

Comment: You know that if you read the answer I gave you 5 minutes ago properly - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433782/writing-a-program-that-compares-2-numbers - you wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: As a bonus, look at http://v.gd/whathaveyoutried

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`=` is an assignment; 
`==` is a comparison.

Comment: so any = is for like defining? and the == sees if the two relate?

Comment: `=` is called assignment operator.  if "defines" or rather assigns a value to variable.  `==` is called comparison operator which returns either True or False.

Comment: @A.R.S. hehe.  i logged in first time this week and got an easy one right away.

Comment: sorry its to easy for you guys lol sigh i need to get better at this, but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

Try this: `if user_input == 30`. In most languages, `=` assigns variables (i.e. `a = 3`), and `==` tests for equality between them (i.e. `a == b`).

Comment: most? I see your C/C++/Java/Python/a-few-others and raise you Fortran, COBOL and a hundred different BASIC dialects :-)

Comment: Yes you are right, I suppose I missspoke. The word "most" sprung to mind simply because Java/C/C++/Python seem to be some of the most popular languages nowadays.